# What exactly do we need to do to work with Service Bus on-premises from a Java client on Linux via AMQP

Tags: java, .net, azure, amqp, servicebus

We are able to connect to an on-premises service bus (Windows Server Service Bus 1.1) using the following connection string:

```
amqps://owner@FQDNofServer:5671/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace
```

Writing to a topic with anonymous access enabled results in `"Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target: "`

Reading from a subscription results in some amqp internal error message.

The Java samples from MS do not shed any light. Can someone [ from MS ] <strike>urgently</strike> provide the info?

Apparently this is all coming with an enterprise SLA, but AFAICS it just does not work.

Comment: If you're going to emphasize "on-premises" in the title with asterisks, you should use the correct term (it's not 'on premise'). I fixed it for you. Also: This isn't a Microsoft-owned Q&A site. Asking *urgently* for help doesn't help. Just... ask.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I haven't lived in an English speaking country since 1997 and my grammar is fading away.... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've just put an article up on MSDN that provides the details. You'll see that things are a little different between Azure Service Bus and Service Bus for Windows Server. Here's the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574799.aspx

Best regards,

Dave.

Comment: Just to confirm, this works. Username and password are windows credentials. Java client implemented to ignore certs.

Comment: So, it is only possible to connect by providing username and password?