# Service Bus on Windows Server (1.1) using Java and AMQP 1.0 Timeout issue

Tags: java, windows, amqp, servicebus

I wrote a test program based on below example to connect to service bus(1.1) installed on windows server using amqp 1.0 java api.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn574799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Everything is fine till session creation. I am getting "Peer did not create remote endpoint for link, target" exception when I tried to create MessageProducer. I used different versions of qpid-amqp-1-0(0.20 to 0.32) but the error is same.

I put some debug statements in source code of qpid-amqp and I observed SendingLinkEndPoint Target became null after few secs.

```
End point target: Target{address=testnamespace/testqueue}
End point target: Target{address=testnamespace/testqueue}
End point target: Target{address=testnamespace/testqueue}
End point target: Target{address=testnamespace/testqueue}
Attach{name=testnamespace/testqueue}

End point target: null

javax.jms.JMSException: Peer did not create remote endpoint for link,    target: testnamespace/testqueue

RECV: com.microsoft:timeout\xa1\xbcThe operation did not complete within the allocated time 00:00:15.0675072 for object connection
```

I made sure the user got domain suffix as per below post

[Connecting to Service Bus on Windows Server (1.1) using Java and AMQP 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963525/connecting-to-service-bus-on-windows-server-1-1-using-java-and-amqp-1-0)

I enabled qpid jms debug in log4j.properties but I dont see any debug statements displayed on the console. Not sure what else I need to do to see what other user oberved(in above post).

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout

log4j.logger.org.apache.qpid.jms=DEBUG

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-15.15t] - %-5p%-30.30c{1} - %m%n
```

the test code looks like below

---

```
String connectionString = "amqps://" + encode(userName) + ":" + encode(password) + "@" + fqdn;

Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,     "org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "blah.txt");
env.put("connectionfactory.ServiceBusConnectionFactory", connectionString);
Context context = null;
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;

Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();                          

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_111\\lib\\security\\cacerts");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",pwd);

Session session = null;
MessageProducer producer = null;

try
{
    System.out.println("Creating session\n");
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);                

    System.out.println("Creating Queue Impl\n");
    QueueImpl queueImpl = QueueImpl.createQueue("testnamespace/testqueue");                        

    System.out.println("Creating producer\n");
    producer = session.createProducer(queueImpl);

}
catch (Exception e)`enter code here`
{
    System.out.println("Exception creating session/producer\n");
    return;
}
```

All the required ports are opened and enabled debug/trace at windows service level in event viewer but I am unable to identify whats the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
S.

Comment: Update - I setup service bus on my home desktop and ran same code. No issues in sending messages from java to service bus using amqp. So, there is some issue with service bu setup in my office desktop or some port blocking/windows policy is causing above issue.

Comment: You don't have RabbitMQ or some other amqp thing installed?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?